# How to add a new team in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My company added my Apple ID to a iTunes connect team, as a "Technical" role.
I want to publish my own app use my Apple ID(has been joined the iOS developer program).But the question is, I can't change to my own team. Every time I enter to "iTunes Connect", I can only see my company's team.So, I can't add new APP in "iTunes Connect".

How can I publish my own app?

Answer (score -1):

You can publish app only with "Admin" role.

Comment: Thank u for your answer.But，how can I add a "Admin" role now?The only way is quit from my company's team?

Comment: You have to publish app by the member who is admin. So you have to quit and add as a admin member.

Comment: @iDeveloper Admin can re-assign the role of the user as Admin.